# Strongest crochet stitch for making a non stretch strap/cord

Tags: crocheting

I have some 3mm dyneema kite line and I'm looking to crochet the line into a strap/cord which can be used to tie things, hoist etc.  What is the strongest crochet stitch which would allow me to achieve this?

Ideally I would have a flat and a round option.

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts.  Can you clarify what you mean by strongest, and why you want to use crochet as the method to form the strap/cord? This may sound like a dumb request, but here is why I ask. It seems like the strength would be defined mainly by the effective number of lines under stress (each leg of each loop that's doing the work). If the pattern is tight, it will hold its shape. But even a loose pattern can't go anywhere unless the pattern is such that it changes shape; e.g., goes from a uniform loop pattern to a collection of tight knots with long strands in between.  (cont'd)

Comment: In that case, it might stretch in length when the pattern changes, but then it would be stable at the new length, with the same strength. I don't crochet so I may be wrong, but my understanding is that the patterns are essentially forms of slip knots that keep their shape because of the connections to adjacent loops. The construction serves more the purpose of a knit, filling space in a decorative way, rather than providing strength under stress. Some type of weave or braid would be tight to start with and wouldn't change the shape of the pattern when under stress.

Comment: Thanks!  Seems like crocheting is not the right way to go, simple braiding is!!! Thank you for the help

Comment: I think@fixer1234 is right. While I didn't make any of it I've got a fair bit of crochet stuff around here including a curtain. It never holds its shape under tension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the wrong craft.

Crocheting your string will thicken up but it will be still be only one strand and any damage that breaks a single strand will break your whole string. And the tight bends in which you force you string in crochet do not work well in dyneema, which is at it strongest straight.

I would go for braiding strands together, at least 8 strands in a round or semi round pattern. With that you do not need to bend your string in tight bends, the several strands will support each other and the failure of one strand will not weaken the whole of your strap.

You can find instruction for braiding online but I have added some I have online, (non commercial site, made by me.)
[Here is the page where I have the links to the braids,](http://knopen.ismijnhobby.nl.bales.id.au/tables/braid-text_table.html) I would go for the eight strands making a square braid, or the round eight with some extra strings for a core. Or using two or three strings for each braiding strand, a 4 strand round braid.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm going to go with a braid using a kumihimo wheel